# C++ compatible parser generator that makes user-friendly error reporting easy

Tags: c++, parser

In my experience, programs which use parser generators to parse domain-specific languages tend to spew cryptic and unhelpful "syntax errors" in case an input cannot be parsed correctly.

Now that I need to write a parser for a domain-specific data language myself (as part of a C++ program), I'd like to hold myself to a higher standard regarding user-friendly error reporting - **and I'm hoping to find a parser generator/framework which can help me with that.**

I'd like to avoid frameworks where the simple and elegant way to write a grammar comes with terrible error reporting, and where adding good error reporting entails so much unintuitive/unelegant refactoring and so much glue code, that it defeats the point of using a framework in the first place.

So I'm hoping that someone more experienced can tell me:

- Which parser generators/frameworks are built with good error reporting in mind?
- What facilities do they provide for error reporting?
  <sup>(Examples or documentation links appreciated!)</sup>

Requirements for the generated parser:

- Callable from C++ code.
- Possible to include in an open-source project (license-wise).
- Cross-platform (Win/Mac/Linux).
- Able to parse a context-free language that could be parsed with a traditional recursive descent parser. (No need for fancy things like left-recursion.)

Comment: I'm not sure this meets your requirements, but have you looked into [Boost Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) framework? (If you've heard of Qi, Karma and Lex, those are names for components of that framework.)

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks for commenting! I haven't looked at Spirit too closely yet, but I'm planning to. :)

Comment: Also, are you sure you need the parser generator _itself_ to be in C++? It's not quite clear how the DSL is part of your C++ program. Perhaps you should elaborate on that some more.

Comment: You're right, the generator doesn't have to be in C++. Updated the question to clarify.